# Rotations about a unit vector which doesn't pass through the origin in 3 dimensions

Tags: homework-and-exercises, vectors, coordinate-systems, rotational-kinematics, rotation

I am trying to understand how rotating a vector about an aribitrary axis which does not pass through the origin of the coordinate system $(x,y,z)$. Let the $\vec{r_{1}} $ and $\vec{r_{2}} $ be two position vectors defined with respect to origin. let $\vec{r_{12}}$ be the difference in the two given position vectors, $\vec{r_{1}}$ and $\vec{r_{2}}$ (i.e),$$\vec{r_{21}}=\vec{r_{2}}-\vec{r_{1}}.$$

If an arbitrary vector $\vec{v}$ is rotated about an axis through angle $\theta$ about a unit vector $\vec{n}$, which passes through origin, the newly rotated vector in terms of the old vector is $$\vec{v}'=(1-\cos\theta)(\vec{n}\cdot\vec{v} )\vec{n}+(\cos\theta )\vec{v}+\sin\theta(\vec{n}\times\vec{v}).$$

If the axis of rotation is $$\vec{r_{21}}$$ and the unit vector along that could be defined as
$$\frac{\vec{r_{21}}}{\mid\vec{r_{21}}\mid}=\vec{n}'$$
let's consider an arbitrary $\vec{r}$ which doesn't pass through the origin
Can I write down the transformed vector $\vec{r}'$ as follows,

$$\vec{r}'=(1-\cos\theta)(\vec{n}'\cdot\vec{r})\vec{n}'+(\cos\theta )\vec{r}+\sin\theta(\vec{n}'\times\vec{r}).$$ Is it correct? Did I make any mistake in the transformation?